# emulate window dimensions in browser

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, browser-width

I'm working on a WYSIWYG editor for building responsive layouts (via Bootstrap), as a side-project. I'm hoping I can build it to work with a zoom/scroll feature (akin to PDF viewers or Photoshop), and allow the user to set/change the dimensions of the 'window' the site is being rendered inside of.

To ensure the WYSIWYG editor is displaying layouts properly, I'd like to put it inside of a div  and set the dimensions of the div to those of the browser window I'm emulating. Is this possible out of the box, using liquid layouts? Otherwise I can edit the JS to look for a target div instead of the window in order to detect dimensions, but I'd prefer the former method.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use css absolute positioning to have a div occupy a defined portion of the browsers viewport regardless of what other html exists. This can be done using px for offset from the browser edges or percentages for a percentage view. So given your example, you could define a 'window' and proceed to layout in that window. Children of elements that are absolutely positioned do not inherit absolute positioning by default so child elements will layout as usual within the position: absolute component.

```
#window {
  position:  absolute;
}
```

As an example of a Bootstrap layout with an absolutely positioned window with components in it that scroll, take a look at:

http://jsfiddle.net/timburgess/ZTt5M/

A List Apart has a good overview of css positioning at http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/